# Where can you find Legendary gear, and is there anything you can do to increase the drop/drop rate?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I haven't seen any legendary equipment drop from anything yet. I've ran my world quest dailies, mythic regular and mythic keystones, cleared Emerald Nightmare on normal, some on heroic-and haven't seen a single legendary. Where can you actually get one? Specific boss/quest? Anything you can do to increase your chances of getting one?

Comment: Basically grind all one-time sources (treasure, rare mobs), world quests (daily chests) and bosses from dungeons and raids, regardless of their difficulty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: it's totally random.

But it's actually not quite just that simple. There is a built-in "bad luck protection" that slightly (it is unknown by how much) increases your chance to get a legendary each time you don't. Some examples of sources of legendaries include:

- Daily world quest caches
- Bosses in Mythic dungeons
- Weekly Mythic+ cache
- Raid bosses
- Withered training end chest
- PvP strongboxes

Answer (score 4):

You can look up information on specific legendaries at [WoWdb](http://wowdb.com). From there you can find the drop rates of specific legendaries and what drops them. For example [Kazzak's Final Curse](http://wowdb.com/items/132374-kazzaks-final-curse) has an estimated 0.003% drop rate from the Wrath of Azshara in Eye of Azshara, 0.3% drop rate from looting the Peerless Challenger's Cache in Halls of Valor and 0.007% drop rate from Kirin Tor Chest in from the Kirin Tor of Dalaran world quests.

As for the drop rates, you have experienced how rare getting a legendary may be. Although Nathan mentions the "bad luck protection", it is still random to get a legendary drop. Each time you complete a task for a legandary, such as killing an NPC or completing a dungeon, there is a dice roll for items in the item drop pool. Each time you roll is independent of the other, meaning an item with a 0.2% drop chance will have a 0.2% chance to be looted each time you loot the item. (The "bad luck protection" is noticeable in the long term but short term is not.)

Comment: There isn't currently any way to actively get a specific legendary, though your wording makes it seems like there is. Blizzard has hinted in the future there might be a way to target a particular one you want.

Comment: I elaborated on legendary drop rates and what they have been reported to drop from. Some legendaries are known to drop from specific NPCs, while some, like you mentioned, can not be farmed as they are random.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm pretty sure those rates you mention are just artifacts of a small sample size and the nature of randomness. For example, the 0.3% chance you cite is only out of ~300 recorded instances while the 0.003% chance is out of ~36,000 recorded instances. The 0.3% chance is not statistically significant. That does not mean it is more likely to come from one source over the other, it is a faulty interpretation of the data.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the post, the item was an example and the drop rates an estimate. However, legendaries such as Thunderfury and the Warlords of Draenor legendary rings are guaranteed quest rewards, although now they are unobtainable.

Comment: I just wanted to make the point that as far as we know all Legion legendaries have an equal chance to drop from all sources, and those numbers do not indicate otherwise.

Comment: The question didn't specify Legion, although it does talk about Legion content, so I answered as such. Yes, Legion legendaries are random but the drop rates are improved for them on difficult content such as raids.

Comment: @NathanK You are correct that the Ring, and as an extension the cloak are now unobtainable but older legendaries like Thunderfury are absolutely still obtainable.

Comment: @Phaeze True. The though question heavily implies Legion legendaries specifically are the focus given the context.

Comment: Just realized I tagged the wrong person in the comment, sorry about that.